# Transformar numero da semana em data no sql server

Tags: sql-server, data

Estou precisando obter a data de uma determinada semana iniciando em novembro de 2021, sendo o início na segundo e o fim no domingo. Por exemplo a semana 2 de 2022 seria 03/01 - 09/01. Se possível nesse formato, ou seja pegar a data da segunda e do domingo e uni-las.

Comment: Salve, Jhonathan. O Stack Overflow não é um serviço de encomenda de código, e sim de solução de problemas. Qual foi o código que você tentou? O que deu errado?

Answer (score -1):

Com a data inicial e final do mês você pode usara função DATEADD(WEEK, 1, DATA) para adicionar as semanas desde seu dia inicial.

```
DECLARE @INICIO AS DATE;
DECLARE @FIM AS DATE;
SET @INICIO = '01/11/2021'
SET @FIM    = '30/11/2021'

SELECT 1 AS SEMANA, @INICIO AS INICIO, DATEADD(DAY, 6, @INICIO) AS FIM
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATEADD(WEEK, 1, @INICIO), DATEADD(WEEK, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 6, @INICIO))
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, DATEADD(WEEK, 2, @INICIO), DATEADD(WEEK, 2, DATEADD(DAY, 6, @INICIO))
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, DATEADD(WEEK, 3, @INICIO), CASE WHEN DATEADD(WEEK, 3, DATEADD(DAY, 6, @INICIO)) > @FIM THEN @FIM ELSE DATEADD(WEEK, 3, DATEADD(DAY, 6, @INICIO)) END

SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @INICIO)
```

Já para saber se os dias estão iniciando na SEG e terminando no DOM use a função DATENAME() COMO MOSTRA A ULTIMA LINHA DO CODIGO.

[## Resultado do código acima ##](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q53yD.png)

Comment: Faltou definir previamente DATEFIRST.